# Display only one object with a given column, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, limit

I have a table :shifts with column :date and belongs_to :user, I want to be able to display all the shifts of a user, but if 2 shifts have the same :date column, I only want to display one (the most recently created one)

I have tried:

```
@shifts = Shift.where(user: user).order(:date).group(:date).take(1)
@shifts = Shift.where(user: user).order(:date).group_by { |t| t.date }.take(1)
```

Neither of them worked, also how would I do this if I where to display shifts from multiple users, in which I only want to display the one shift per day of each user? I am using postgres

Comment: Why that doesn't work?, `group` by itself should give you the most recent record by grouping for the attribute used.

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "shifts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function, the error I get

Comment: You must add the model id when using `group`, try `Shift.where(user: user).order(:date).group(:id, :date)`, what do you get?

Comment: It does not crash, but when I plug in limit(1) it only loads 1 row, instead of 1 row per date

Answer (score 0):

```
Shift.where(user: user).select(:date).order(:date).group(:date)
```

OR

```
user.shifts.select(:date).order(:date).group(:date)
```

Comment: the end result cannot be displayed with a .each do how do I use this?